# PHP error notices. Should they never be ignored?

Tags: php

I'm researching how to better organize my website content with PHP, and I had a question regarding unimportant error notices.

[image: PhP Notices in question]

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['filename']) {
    case 'home':
        require('src/home.php');
    break;
    case 'quiz';
        require('src/quiz.php');
    break;
    default:
        if ($_GET['filename'] == '') {
            include('src/home.php');
        } else {
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
            include('src/page_not_found.php');
        }
    break;
}
?>
```

For example here; it's obviously telling me that it's getting undefined when I try to get the filename in the URL parameter. In this context, it's empty, and I'm doing this on purpose to check if there's something in there and if it should be interpreted as one of my other files.

I'm aware that you can add "error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);" at the start of the line to hide the notice and the website will work just fine like that, but I was wondering if this is something I should always "fix"?

I was thinking of doing an if condition before the switch case:

```
if ($_GET['filename'] == ""){
    include('src/home.php');
}
```

But that will throw me a notice as well, since what I am checking is undefined and will trigger the error notice regardless. What should I do?

Comment: Instead of checking for the index and hoping it is there, you could use `isset()`, like `if(isset($_GET['filename']))`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks Tim! I'll edit my question right away

Comment: No problem! Note that in some PHP frameworks, these kinds of notices are actually converted to errors, so it's best to handle them when you can  Please feel free to modify your code to a state where `isset()` handles those, and post an answer below. Cheers!

Comment: You can use [??](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-null-coalescing-operator/) in php 7+. Example: `($_GET['filename'] ?? null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Lewis answered my question, *thank you by the way!*; Instead of hoping that a file is there, you can instead use `isset()`.

So, instead of what I made, I would do something like this, to first check if the content is set before doing anything else:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['filename'])){
        include('src/home.php');
    } else {
        switch ($_GET['filename']) {
            case 'home':
                require('src/home.php');
            break;
            case 'quiz';
                require('src/quiz.php');
            break;
            default:
                header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                include('src/page_not_found.php');
            break;
        }   
    }
?>
```